# Bigquery export data output is not in proper order

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, bigquery-udf

I am trying to export a table from Bigquery to single file in GCS.
But my output is not in sorted order.

```
export data options(uri = 'gs://<bucket><object>/file1_*.csv', format = 'CSV',overwrite = true, header = true, field_delimiter = '|') as select distinct * from (select * from table1 where country not in (select distinct(country) from table2) order by col_rnk)
```

distinct * has been used to get the output into single file in GCS.

Any help would be great !

Comment: Does the output bigger than 1gb?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should move `ORDER BY col_rnk` out side .

with that please try the below

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
  uri = 'gs://<bucket>/<object>/file1_*.csv',
  format = 'CSV',
  overwrite = true,
  header = true,
  field_delimiter = '|'
) AS
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM table1
  WHERE country NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT(country)
    FROM table2
  )
)
ORDER BY col_rnk
```

**NOT THE PART OF ANSWER TO THE ABOVE QUESTION BUT TO DRAWN ATTANTATION TO THE FOLLOWING POINTS.**

please take a look at [query-syntax#select_distinct](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select_distinct)

> **SELECT DISTINCT**
>
> A SELECT DISTINCT statement discards duplicate rows
> and returns only the remaining rows. SELECT DISTINCT cannot return
> columns of the following types:
>
> 1.STRUCT
>
> 2.ARRAY

also can you verify the logic and try without the uses of `SELECT DISTINCT *`

please consider the following approach

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
  uri = 'gs://<bucket>/<object>/file1_*.csv',
  format = 'CSV',
  overwrite = true,
  header = true,
  field_delimiter = '|'
) AS
SELECT col1, col2, col_rnk
FROM (
  SELECT col1, col2, col_rnk
  FROM table1
  WHERE country NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT(country)
    FROM table2
  )
)
ORDER BY col_rnk
```

Comment: Should change nothing. I think the problem is more about the design of BigQuery

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thanks for your valuable remark , it will be helpful if you take a look at the edit part of the answer  and verify above approach .

Comment: my point is: BigQuery is a distributed system (each element is named SLOT). When you run an extract with a wild card, a set of SLOTS is used to write the file in the bucket. And the files are not necessarily written in order. I have to admit I never tested, but the design of BigQuery could be a challenge.

Comment: now you made me dive init more deep , thanks @guillaumeblaquiere
 :). i will edit the answer if found any better.